# Shorter equivalent to (un)replaced

Tags: single-word-requests

This may be aimed more at developers; but lets say you have a string with a possible variable in it assigned to another variable.

```
$myVarBeforeReplacement = 'some_string_with_{var}';
```

Then after some manipulation you get the desired string by *replacing* that variable

```
$myVarAfterReplacement = 'some_string_with_its_var_replaced';
```

I am trying to think of two separate but somewhat related words to describe the string in each stage. I don't want to use `processed` / `unprocessed` as that can imply at the other processes going on.

Similarly I don't want to used `formatted` / `unformatted` since the string can also go through formatting. `Replaced` / `unreplaced` seems a little long winded and antiquated.

I was leaning on `raw` but cooked(?) makes no sense.

Comment: I would usually call the former a "dynamic string" as its content is being determined at runtime. That would arguably make the replacement one a "static string" but that seems a bit silly, so I would personally just call it a replacement string.

Answer (score 3):

The first is a string, but it is also a *template* and it is *unresolved*.

The *resulting string*, has been *resolved*.

So it is fair to call them the *template* and the *resolved template*.  It's also fair to call them the *template* and the *resulting string* or *result*, depending on the context.

Normally, I would call them the *template* and the *result*.

Answer (score 1):

A few others that nobody's mentioned yet:

- *input - output* is an obvious general candidate
- *reference - sense* captures the philosophical distinction

And, since you're talking about functions,

- *argument - value* also works.